# Nix package manager: how to have uuidgen command?

Tags: linux, macos, nixos

I am new to nix and nixos and I want to have the `uuidgen` command available. I don't see `uuid-runtime` and `linux-utils` didn't contained it. I don't see any specific documentation on how to get this command. Any help appreciated. I'm on MacOS using the nix package manager, and also have a linux machine.

Comment: I don't understand your tags of nixos and macos in the same question.  Which is it?  The ***Nix*** package manager can be used under macos but ***nixos*** is its own NON-APPLE distro that comes with the nix package manager as it's default and is entirely configured via the Nix package manager.  The "OS" part is the giveaway.

Answer (score 3):

`uuidgen` can be found in the [`libuuid` package](https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=21.11&show=libuuid&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=libuuid).

Comment: I like your answer (esp since other people didn't bother to answer it).